# How to use gst along with pyqt to stream video on pyqt widget

Tags: python, gstreamer

Am using gst along with my pyqt. I want to display the video stream in my widget. While doing so my application starts streaming the video and then crashes. What am I doing wrong ?

Camera Code

```
from PyQt4 import QtCore

import gst


class camThread(QtCore.QThread):
    updateImage = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str)
    flag = None

def __init__(self,windowId):
    QtCore.QThread.__init__(self)    
    self.windowId =windowId                                   
    self.player = gst.parse_launch("udpsrc port=5000 !  application/x-rtp, encoding-name=H264, payload=96 !  rtph264depay ! h264parse ! ffdec_h264 ! autovideosink")                            
    bus = self.player.get_bus()
    bus.add_signal_watch()
    bus.enable_sync_message_emission()

    bus.connect("sync-message::element", self.on_sync_message)  
    self.bus = bus     



def on_sync_message(self, bus, message):
    print "akash 123"
    if message.structure is None:
        return
    message_name = message.structure.get_name()
    if message_name == "prepare-xwindow-id":
        win_id = self.windowId
        assert win_id
        imagesink = message.src
        imagesink.set_property("force-aspect-ratio", True)
        imagesink.set_xwindow_id(win_id)               

def run(self):
    print "akash"               
    self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_PLAYING)
    msg = self.bus.timed_pop_filtered(gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE,
                                 gst.MESSAGE_ERROR | gst.MESSAGE_EOS)


    self.flag = True
    while(True):
        if(self.flag==False):
            break

def quit(self):
    self.flag = false
    self.player.set_state(gst.STATE_NULL)

    #self.cap.release()
```

Calling code

```
def stopCam(self):
    if(self.cam!=None):                             
        self.cam.quit()
        self.cam = None

def startCam(self):

    if(self.cam==None):                       
        self.cam = camThread(self.pic.winId())


        self.cam.start()

    elif(self.cam.isRunning()):            
        pass
```

What am I doing wrong ? Here is the entire code on paste bin

[PasteBin file 1](http://pastebin.com/DGQRUHF9)
[PasteBin file 2](http://pastebin.com/CdCFueSb)

Edit:

I opened the python in debugger. The application becomes unresponsive/fails, when I start the gst playing i.e. it fails after gst bus timed pop. 
One of the possible reason I could see was that a thread relating to the video streaming stops or exits after it is started in the application. After which the application goes black/unresponsive/crashes.

Comment: Crashes normally mean something is wrong within the C/C++ world. Things that come to mind are freed memory that is still used or invalid addresses. So you need to find out where the crash happens. For that, start the Python-interpreter in GDB. Then run your program from there, and report back here on where the crash-site is.

Comment: What happens if you run the gstreamer pipeline manually?

Comment: It works properly. The gstreamer works perfectly even when I use autovideosink.

Comment: @AkashDeshpande please fix the indentation on your code

Comment: The first excerpt is still not correct. I have verified your woes on my computer (you might want to make a simpler GST graph that still causes the same problem, I try `v4l2src ! autovideosink` - I do not even know where to install `h264parse`

Comment: @AnttiHaapala right. You can install h264 parse with the restricted plugin in ubuntu. I will try and reproduce this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you forgot to initialise the threading system.

```
import gobject
gobject.threads_init()
import gst
```

Your `run()` function also does not need the while loop and the flag `self.flag`. According to the documentation [here](https://people.gnome.org/~gcampagna/docs/Gst-1.0/Gst.Bus.timed_pop_filtered.html), the call to `timed_pop_filtered(gst.CLOCK_TIME_NONE, ...)` will block until it receives the specified message. When you click on the "Stop Cam" button, you terminate the playback. The flag is never used.

I also had to change `self.cam = camThread(self.pic.winId())` to `self.cam = camThread(int(self.pic.winId()))` and comment out `imagesink.set_property("force-aspect-ratio", True)`
-- I am using Mac OS X.

Hope this helps.